# Resampling time series data from one column into multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying resample the column "lang" in the below dataset into two columns that tell us the count of each value ("zh" and "en") respective in each period (let's just say in each week), given the dataset is a pandas dataframe. Does anyone know how I can make it? I found that .resample() might be a way out but I can only find examples that handle data within the column. Thanks!

```
    date    lang
2019-05-01 07:59:42+00:00   zh
2019-05-04 07:57:53+00:00   en
2019-05-06 07:52:40+00:00   zh
2019-05-08 07:43:38+00:00   en
2019-05-10 07:40:40+00:00   zh
2019-05-13 07:37:25+00:00   zh
2019-05-16 07:31:55+00:00   zh
2019-05-18 07:15:53+00:00   en
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. For the given input, what should the output be?

Comment: the output should contains more than one column from "lang" so that it shows the count of each value within "lang" e.g. 

 date    zh en
2019-05-01  2 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date'), 'lang']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```